# Chrome Extension - Trigger alert when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing simple extension for Chrome.

I have included jquery in the extension and all what i want to do is when google.com is loaded to fine an simple alert message.

Comment: You set the alert to trigger when the background page is ready. Put the `alert` code **inside** the `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted` listener.

Comment: I tried and it's still not working.

Comment: Don't use the same script as [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts): they have different purposes, requirements and limitations. For example, `chrome.webNavigation` won't work on a content script.

Comment: It should be noted you don't need the background page at all for this task. Neither jQuery is needed. Simply use `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]` and `"include_globs": ["*.google.*"]`, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: Did you developped that extension? If yes what is it's name?

Answer (score 3):

Alert executes because it's outside the `onCompleted` handler.

You don't even need jQuery here. 
The simplest way to do what you asked:

**background.js**

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function (details) {
        if (details.url && details.url.match(/www\.google\.com/)) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {
                code: 'alert("Page is done")'
            });
        }
    },
    {
        url: [{hostContains: '.google.'}]
    }
);
```

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "IBPLN",
    "description": "Instant Banking Page Load Notification",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "webNavigation",
        "*://*/*",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
    ]
}
```

You still may need to tune URL patterns to catch only requests you need.

Advice: do not use the same script for [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) page and [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). They have different purposes.